# How can I extend ng's IModule interface in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to extend `ng.IModule` to support custom component registrations, but it constantly gives me same error:

> Property 'customComponent' does not exist on type 'IModule'.ts(2339)

Here's my code:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "module": "amd",
    ...
    "types": [
        "angular"
    ]
}
```

**Module.ts**

```
export class Module {
    register(module: ng.IModule) {
        module
            .component(SomeComponent, SomeComponent.componentOptions)
            .customComponent("test") <-- this what it doesn't work
       ;
   }
}
```

**ModuleExtension.ts**

```
export declare module ng {
    interface IModule {
        customComponent(testData: string): IModule;
    }
}
```

`ng` namespace is global one.

I read TS documentation and what I'm trying achieve is called [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). In C# it was called extension methods.

Comment: Where did you imported `ng` and `IModule`?

Comment: As I said, `ng` is global namespace and `IModule` is part of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving it to a `.d.ts` file instead of a `.ts` file. Then you can also lose the `export`. I tried locally and this fixes the issue, also with `ng` as a global namespace.

Comment: Hymm, same issue: `Property 'customComponent' does not exist on type 'IModule'.`. I checked with and without `export`

Comment: Weird, which version of TypeScript are you using? What if you replace module with namespace?

Comment: I am using TS 3.0.3. Replacing `module` with `namespace` changed nothing :(

Comment: Should I include somehow this `.d.ts` file? In tsconfig I include `**/*.ts' files, so that one should be cought.

Comment: Actually, it is. I found that I was using `["*", "../node_modules/*"]` in my tsconfig.json. Changing the first one to `"*.ts"` broke imports of `.d.ts` files until I added that to my configuration too. So `["*.ts", "*.d.ts", "../node_modules/*"]` seems to work